# Android Deep Linking with multiple query parameters

Tags: android, adb, deep-linking

I'm trying to deep link my app and have implemented the following in my AndroidManifest.xml to open the proper activity.

```
<activity
    android:name=".ui.activities.MyActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <!-- ATTENTION: This intent was auto-generated. Follow instructions at
    https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio to publish your Android app deep links. -->
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <!-- ATTENTION: This data URL was auto-generated. We recommend that you use the HTTP scheme.
        TODO: Change the host or pathPrefix as necessary. -->
        <data
            android:host="myHost"
            android:scheme="myCustomScheme" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

And I'm testing the activity from adb using

```
adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "myCustomScheme://myHost?key=category_parent_id&value=92&title=test" com.myApp.android
```

The Activity is opening but the URI which is passed to the activity in the intent is only

```
myCustomScheme://myHost?key=category_parent_id
```

Its skipping everything after '&'

I did look up here on SO but didn't find anything with multiple query parameters.

Answer (score 240, accepted):

Just add `\` before `&` sign when testing with adb.

Copy this:

`adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "myCustomScheme://myHost?key=category_parent_id\&value=92\&title=test" com.myApp.android`

Comment: Worked for me. Does anyone know why do you need to do this?

Comment: Also, if the `title` field has white-spaces then prefix them too with backslashes.

Comment: I was missing the `\ ` before the `&`. Thanks, dude!

Comment: When I have the query parameter in the URL, Android system not not showing my app in suggestions but without query params it's working. Please  what couldhelp be the issue. URL: "myCustomScheme://myHost?key=xxx"

Comment: In the real world its either "" or \ - never both - what was Google thinking here ?

Comment: yes it works with `\` from adb, but from email message it still opens link with first parameter only!

Comment: In my case for some unknown reason I had to append one extra unescaped ampersand, e. g. "myCustomScheme://myHost?key=category_parent_id\&value=92\&title=test&"

Comment: I use %26 instead of & and It works in adb and browser

Comment: It does not work when defining deep link URI, in uri you should use &amp;

Answer (score 58):

You can wrap the shell command with simple quotes (to avoid modifying the uri content):

```
adb shell 'am start -d "myCustomScheme://myHost?key=category_parent_id&value=92&title=test"'
```

Comment: This is should be the accepted answer since it doesn't require changing the URI or doing any encoding

Comment: what about link in email?

Answer (score 4):

For osx / mac users with android studio

Load adb

```
export PATH="/Users/your_user/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools":$PATH
```

Check that the app is recognized

```
adb shell am start -n com.package/.activities_package_name.MainActivity
```

Test deeplink

```
adb shell 'am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "myCustomScheme://myHost?key=category_parent_id\&value=92\&title=test" com.myApp.android'
```

Don't forget the ' '

Comment: from email it also skips

Answer (score 2):

Just encode your url parameters and it will work.
It might be google's parsing bug.

Before:

```
adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "myCustomScheme://myHost?key=category_parent_id&value=92&title=test" com.myApp.android
```

After:

```
adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "myCustomScheme://myHost?key%3Dcategory_parent_id%26value%3D92%26title%3Dtest" com.myApp.android
```