# Deep Linking Android with "&" character

Tags: android, deep-linking

I want a user to be able to login using magic a link as below:

```
myapp://app.com/login-with-token?email=someEmail&token=sometoken
```

For some reason the app only receives the part before `&` character as:

```
myapp://app.com/login-with-token?email=someEmail
```

Does anybody have an idea how to work around this problem?

EDIT: Here's what I've added in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
          <data android:scheme="myapp"
              android:host="app.com"
              android:pathPrefix="/"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: How are you using the link? Redirected from javascript, php, in-app?

Comment: For now, I'm only testing it in Android Studio: 
Run -> Edit Configurations -> Launch URL

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `&` instead of `?` for the query param?

Comment: @SimonMarquis There's no particular reason, it's just what our backend returns and it works perfectly on iOS. Seems like we'll have to replace `&` with `?`.

Comment: Yes, query should begin with `?`, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Syntax

Comment: Thanks for the link, @SimonMarquis! 

I've tried `myapp://app.com/login-with-token?email=someEmail;token=sometoken` with no success, though it follows the convention as well.


`myapp://app.com/login-with-token?email=someEmail?token=sometoken` works nice by the way.

Comment: The correct format would be: `myapp://app.com/login-with-token?email=someEmail&token=somet‌​oken`

Comment: it does follow the format.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Deep Linking with multiple query parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35645414/android-deep-linking-with-multiple-query-parameters)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out the question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35645414/android-deep-linking-with-multiple-query-parameters).

**SOLUTION**:

`\` has to be added before `&` when testing with adb/Android Studio.