# Deeplink URL for android

Tags: android, deep-linking, deeplink

How to create deeplink url for our application which accepts parameters also?

I have tried using

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:scheme="my-scheme" 
android:host="my.host.name"
                android:pathPrefix="/data?name=[text]&amp;token=[text]"></data>
        </intent-filter>
```

but not working.Can anyone please help me if I have to launch my app using

```
my-scheme://my.host.name/data?name=MY_NAME&token=MY_TOKEN;
```

Comment: Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35645414/android-deep-linking-with-multiple-query-parameters

Comment: Thanks..It is working now...

Comment: Honestly it's best if you read the official documentation first. The answer is there already https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking.html

Answer (score 0):

Replace `android:scheme="my-scheme"` with `android:scheme="https"`
and then try to access the website at 
`https://my.host.name/data?name=MY_NAME&token=MY_TOKEN`. Also replace the host with a your website name.

Comment: is this android:pathPrefix="/data?name=[text]&amp;token=[text]" correct???