# Jetpack Navigation deeplink with query parameters

Tags: android, regex, url, query-string, android-architecture-navigation

it looks like it isn't possible to process a deeplink with query parameters in the new Jetpack Navigation library. If you put the following to the navigation.xml:
`<deepLink app:uri="scheme://host/path?query1={query_value}" />` then the deeplink does not open the fragment.

After some digging I found that the culprit is probably in the NavDeepLink when it transforms the url from xml to a Pattern regex. Looks like the problem is a question mark that is not excaped.

I wrote a test which fails:

```
@Test
fun test() {
    val navDeepLink = NavDeepLink("scheme://host/path?query1={query_value}")
    val deepLink = Uri.parse("scheme://host/path?query1=foo_bar")
    assertEquals(true, navDeepLink.matches(deepLink))
}
```

To make the test pass all I have to do is to escape the ? as following:

```
@Test
fun test() {
    val navDeepLink = NavDeepLink("scheme://host/path\\?query1={query_value}")
    val deepLink = Uri.parse("scheme://host/path?query1=foo_bar")
    assertEquals(true, navDeepLink.matches(deepLink))
}
```

Am I missing something really basic here to pass query values to my Fragment or is this not supported feature at the moment?

Answer (score 23):

You need to add DeepLink Navigation to AndroidManifest.xml ( special Activity that handles the fragment) so when deeplink clicked your app can receive the DeepLink and pass it to that navigation and  fragment & can read it as argument:

I'll put Kotlin codes here :

In your navigation file, your fragment that gonna handle the deeplink with arguements must be like this:

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/menu"
        android:name="ir.hamplus.fragments.MainFragment"
        android:label="MainFragment">

    <action android:id="@+id/action_menu_to_frg_messenger_main" 
     app:destination="@id/frg_messenger_main"/>

    <deepLink app:uri="http://hamplus.ir/request/?key={key}&amp;id={id}" />

    <argument android:name="key" app:argType="string"/>
    <argument android:name="id" app:argType="string"/>

</fragment>
```

read deeplink arguments in frasgment /Activity :

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
  //Or in activity read the intent?.data
       arguments?.let {
            Log.i("TAG", "Argument=$arguments")

            var key = it.getString("key")
            Log.i("TAG", "key=$key")

            var id = it.getString("id")
            Log.i("TAG", "id=$id")

        }
}
```

Also add the nav-graph on AndroidManifest.xml in related Activity :

```
 <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >

    <nav-graph android:value="@navigation/main_navigation"/>

</activity>
```

Comment: If the activity is not the main one, how do you start it?

Answer (score 0):

```
package androidx.navigation

import android.net.Uri
import androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4
import org.junit.Assert.assertTrue
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class NavTest {
    @Test
    fun test() {
        val navDeepLink = NavDeepLink("scheme://host/path\\?query1={query_value1}&query2={query_value2}")
        val deepLink = Uri.parse("scheme://host/path?query1=foo_bar&query2=baz")

        val bundle = navDeepLink.getMatchingArguments(deepLink)!!
        assertTrue(bundle.get("query_value1") == "foo_bar")
        assertTrue(bundle.get("query_value2") == "baz")
    }
}
```

In the end it looks like NavDeepLink treats non escaped as "?" [match-zero-or-one quantifier](http://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/manual/Regular_expressions_1__Special_characters.html). You need to escape it. In other words, we have a leak of non documented implementation detail.

<s>It might be not related to the exactly this case, but there is some similar issues with escaping "&" with "\" [when using add command.](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37003806)</s>

The issue was also touched [in the following channel.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35645414/android-deep-linking-with-multiple-query-parameters)