# Firebase PendingDynamicLinkData in Android is null

Tags: java, android, firebase, null, firebase-dynamic-links

Here are the full steps what I have done:

1. Have updated ***firebase.json*** with the following:

   `"appAssociation": "AUTO", "rewrites": [ { "source": "/product/**", "dynamicLinks": true } ]`
2. My website domain ***example.com*** is hosted in Firebase. So, uploaded ***firebase.json*** using ***firebase deploy --only hosting***
3. Added the following Dynamic URL prefix in ***Firebase Dynamic Links***

   `https://example.com/product`

[Screenshot of Firebase Dynamic Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEGUP.jpg)

4. Implemented ***bom, dynamic-links and analytics*** in ***build.gradle(:app)*** file

```
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.0.3')

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
```

5. Created a Dynamic link using the following code:

```
private void handleFirebaseDynamicLink() {
        DynamicLink dynamicLink = FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance().createDynamicLink()
                .setLink(Uri.parse("https://example.com/product/?productSKU=" + ProductSKU))
                .setDomainUriPrefix("https://example.com/product/")
                .setAndroidParameters(
                        new DynamicLink.AndroidParameters.Builder("com.myapp.myapp").build())
                .buildDynamicLink();


        try {
            String url = URLDecoder.decode(dynamicLink.getUri().toString(), "UTF-8");
            Log.d(TAG, "handleFirebaseDynamicLink: " + url);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

6. Dynamic Link generated from above method is:

```
https://example.com/product/?apn=com.myapp.myapp&link=https://example.com/product/?productSKU=SKU-0004
```

7. To receive the dynamic link have created the following intent filter to my activity in ***AndroidManifest.xml*** file:

```
<activity
            android:name=".Product_Details">

            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="example.com"
                    android:pathPrefix="/product"
                    android:scheme="https" />
            </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

8. A method in ***onCreate()*** by calling  -

```
//Fetching productSKU
fetchProductSKU(getIntent());
```

receives the dynamic link as follows:

```
private void fetchProductSKU(Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction() != null) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)) {
                FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance()
                        .getDynamicLink(intent)
                        .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<PendingDynamicLinkData>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(PendingDynamicLinkData pendingDynamicLinkData) {
                                // Get deep link from result (may be null if no link is found)
                                Uri deepLink = null;
                                if (pendingDynamicLinkData != null) {
                                    deepLink = pendingDynamicLinkData.getLink();
                                    Log.d(TAG, "handleFirebaseDynamicLink: " + deepLink);
                                } else {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "handleFirebaseDynamicLink: pendingDynamicLinkData null");
                                }


                                // Handle the deep link. For example, open the linked
                                // content, or apply promotional credit to the user's
                                // account.
                                // ...

                                // ...
                            }
                        })
                        .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                Log.w(TAG, "getDynamicLink:onFailure", e);
                            }
                        });

            }
        }
    }
```

9. Using ADB Shell command on my physical mobile device I test the dynamic link using the following -

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -c android.intent.category.BROWSABLE -d "https://example.com/product/?apn=com.myapp.myapp&link=https://example.com/product/?productSKU=SKU-0004"
```

10. This in turn launches the intended Activity. However, ***pendingDynamicLinkData*** returns null.

```
2022-01-03 17:29:15.141 12914-12914/com.myapp.myapp D/Product_Details: handleFirebaseDynamicLink: pendingDynamicLinkData null
```

11. I have tried -

a. Using Different Dynamic Link prefixes like - ***/product*** (without the "/" at the end like ***/product/***), without the query parameter ***/?productSKU=" + ProductSKU*** in the end of ***.setLink*** and ***.setDomainUriPrefix*** while building dynamic link,

b. By only converting created dynamic link using ***dynamicLink.getUri().toString()*** instead of the ***URLDecoder.decode(dynamicLink.getUri().toString(), "UTF-8")*** method.

12. None of the above worked. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

After some more research and little bit of debugging it looks like multiple parameters in URL are being removed by intent in Android during testing through ADB. However, only the first parameter is preserved.

Hence in my case only `apn` parameter is saved while the `link` parameter is removed by intent. Hence, pendingDynamicLinkData returns null.

The generated dynamic link if sent through email works fine.

Removing multiple parameters by intent in android is explained by the following thread:

> [Android Deep Linking with multiple query parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35645414/android-deep-linking-with-multiple-query-parameters)